# XML Error: Open quote is expected for attribute id associated with an element type

Tags: java, xml, sax, parseexception

I am trying to parse an XML file shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE COUNTRIES_CONTINENT PUBLIC 
           "-//XYZ//DTD Declarations(CountriesContinent)//EN" "dtds/countries_continent.dtd">
<COUNTRIES_CONTINENT>
   <CONTINENT id="6" name="Oceania" value="12">
       <COUNTRY name="Argentina"/>
       <COUNTRY name="Bolivia"/>
       <COUNTRY name="Brazil"/>
       <COUNTRY name="Chile"/>
        <COUNTRY name="Colombia"/>
        <COUNTRY name="Ecuador"/>
        <COUNTRY name="Guyana"/>
        <COUNTRY name="Paraguay"/>
        <COUNTRY name="Peru"/>
        <COUNTRY name="Suriname"/>
        <COUNTRY name="Uruguay"/>
        <COUNTRY name="Venezuela"/>
    </CONTINENT>
</COUNTRIES_CONTINENT>
```

Having the following DTD file:

```
<!ELEMENT COUNTRIES_CONTINENT (CONTINENT+)>
<!ELEMENT CONTINENT (COUNTRY+)>
<!ELEMENT COUNTRY EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST CONTINENT id  CDATA  ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST CONTINENT name  CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST CONTINENT value CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST COUNTRY   name CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
Open quote is expected for the attribute "id" associated with an element type "CONTINENT".
```

Can anyone point out what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<!ATTLIST CONTINENT id  CDATA  ID #REQUIRED>
```

The attribute type can be either `CDATA` or `ID`, but it cannot be both.  Each of these types has its own rules describing the ranges of values that they are allowed to contain. Please check which type is what you expected for `id`.

see http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_attributes.asp